# Is it feasible to encrypt uploaded file using external tools than inside the script?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, security

I want to encrypt the files that are uploaded by users of a web application.

The files need to be encrypted and decrypted individually.

Are there advantages to encrypting the file using an external tool than inside the application?

For example calling gpg, crypt or 7zip (or any other tool) immediately after a file was uploaded.

Upon request for a retrieval, call them again to decrypt, then serve the file.

I thought this may have performance advantages as well as the fact that encryption can be outsourced to a potentially more robust and well trusted application than the library available in the programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launching an tool creates a new process every time, which can impact scalability. There are libraries as respectable as tools, some of them from the same codebase.

Comment: It would be possible to create background workers with a queue and have a flag in the db to mark it as completed after worker is done encrypting it. It's a bit more salable. Sounds like an overkill, though. Just an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't implement your own crypto.  That said, the alternatives don't look that different to me.  Surely you can use GPG either in-process (called via an API) or out-of-process (with parameters passed on the command line).  Then the considerations come down to the usual engineering ones of performance, robustness, etc and really have nothing in particular to do with cryptography.